# Ubuntu - Add user to usergruoup

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have installed Ubuntu in VirtualBox and need to add my user to the vboxuser group.
I can see that I need to write the command sudo usermod -aG vboxusers  in a ternal window, but I can't figure out if it should be in Ubuntu or in Windows.

In Windows I get the error that 'sudo' is not a valid command and ind Ubuntu I get the error that the group vboxuser does not exist.

Comment: Why do you want to add your user to the *vboxusers* group?

Comment: I have installed Oracle VM Virtualbox Extension Pack to be able to connect to an external USB harddrive. But I need to add my user to the group to be anle to choose USB 2.0 or USB 3.0.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Comment: The information you're looking at has Linux as the host OS. This isn't what you have.

Answer (score 0):

On linux for add a group you've to use these comand :
for create a goup :

```
sudo addgroup groupname
```

For add an user in the group :

```
sudo adduser user groupname
```

On windows is quite different than bash shell you 've on Linux.
Here the generic command for add a group :

```
net localgroup "groupname" /add
```

For add an user in the group

```
net localgroup "groupname " "User" /add
```

For delete an user from the group

```
net localgroup "groupname " "User" /delete
```

or use the interface with the command :

```
lusrmgr.msc
```

The term `User` should be replaced by the login you want to add as well.